# Is Haskell a strongly typed programming language?

Tags: haskell, type-systems

Is Haskell strongly typed? I.e. is it possible to change the type of a variable after you assigned one? I can't seem to find the answer on the internet.

Comment: Whether Haskell is strongly typed depends on whether you like its type system or not. See http://ericlippert.com/2012/10/15/is-c-a-strongly-typed-or-a-weakly-typed-language/

Comment: ["Strongly-typed" and "weakly-typed" are ill defined.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/38257/102349) You probably mean to ask if Haskell is dynamically typed (no, it's not).

Comment: Note that in Haskell, you can't even change the *value* of a variable after it's assigned; so even if Haskell were dynamically typed, the runtime-type of a variable would be fixed at assignment.

Comment: @EricLippert how about mapping _weak = type-unsafe_ and _strong = type-safe_? how about the rest of my version of the definitions below? however, memsafety, I think — if you mean memory allocation and pointer dereferencing — should be viewed as yet one layer below type safety, which is in turn one layer below static type safety.

Comment: @ErikAllik: Thank you for so aptly illustrating my central point: that these terms are so ill-defined that you have to have a careful explanation calling out precisely which kinds of safety and guarantees you mean to express. Also, what do you do about languages like C# that are for the most part type safe but have an unsafe subset for interoperating with C programs?  Is such a language strongly typed because it is *typically* typesafe, or weakly typed because it *can* be type unsafe?  Again, we have to carefully delineate what we mean.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Static** — types are known at compile time. Java and Haskell have static typing. Also C/C++, C#, Go, Scala, Rust, Kotlin, Pascal to list a few more.

A statically typed language might or might not have type inference. Java almost completely lacks type inference (but it's very slowly changing just a little bit); Haskell has full type inference (except with certain very advanced extensions).

(Type inference is when you only have to declare a minimal amount of types by hand, e.g. `var isFoo = true` and `var person = new Person()`, instead of `bool isFoo = ...` and `Person person = ...`.)

**Dynamic** — Python, JavaScript, Ruby, PHP, Clojure (and Lisps in general), Prolog, Erlang, Groovy etc. Can also be called "unityped"; dynamic typing can be "emulated" in a static setting, but the reverse is not true except by using external static analysis tools. Some languages make it possible to mix dynamic and static (see [gradual typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradual_typing), e.g. https://typedclojure.org/).

Some languages enable static typing for one or more modules, applied at import time, for example: [Python+Mypy](http://mypy-lang.org), [Typed Clojure](http://typedclojure.org), [JavaScript+Flow](https://flow.org), [PHP+Hack](https://hacklang.org) to name a few.

**Strong** — values that are intended to be treated as `Cat` always are; trying to treat them like a `Dog` will cause a loud `meeewww`... I mean error.

**Weak** — this effectively boils down to 2 similar but distinct things: type coercion (e.g. `"5"+3` equals `8` in PHP — or does it!) and memory reinterpretation (e.g. `(int) someCharValue` or `(bool) somePtr` in C, and C++ as well, but C++ wants you to explicitly say `reinterpret_cast`). So there's really *coercion-weak* and *reinterpretation-weak*, and different languages are weak in one or both of these ways.

Interestingly, note that coercion is implicit by nature and memory reinterpretation is explicit (except in Assembly) — so weak typing consists of an implicit *and* an explicit behavior. Maybe that's even more of a reason to refer to 2 distinct subcategories under weak typing.

---

There are languages with all 4 possible combinations, and variations/gradations thereof.

**Haskell is static+strong**; of course it has `unsafeCoerce` so it can be static+a bit reinterpret-weak at times, but `unsafeCoerce` is very much frowned upon except in extreme situations where you are sure about something being the case but just can't seem to persuade the compiler without going all the way back and retelling the entire story in a different way.

**C is static+weak** because all memory can freely be reinterpreted as something it originally was not meant to contain, hence weak. But all of those reinterpretations are kept track of by the type checker, so still fully static too. But C does not do implicit coercions, so it's only *reinterpret-weak*.

**Python is dynamic+almost entirely strong** — there are no types known on any given line of code prior to reaching that line during execution, however values that live at runtime do have types associated with them and it's impossible to reinterpret memory. Implicit coercions are also kept to a meaningful minimum, so one might say Python is 99.9% strong and 0.01% *coercion-weak*.

**PHP and JavaScript are dynamic+mostly weak** — dynamic, in that nothing has type until you execute and introspect its contents, and also weak in that coercions happen all the time and with things you'd never really expect to be coerced, unless you are only calling methods and functions and not using built-in operations. These coercions are a source of a lot of humor on the internet. There are no memory reinterpretations so PHP and JS are *coercion-weak*.

---

Furthermore, some people like to think that static typing is about variables having type, and strong typing is about values having type — this is a very useful way to go about understanding the full picture, but it's *not quite true*: some dynamically typed languages also allow variables/parameters to be annotated with types/constraints that are enforced at runtime.

In static typing, it's expressions that have a type; the fact of variables having type is only a consequence of variables being used as a means to glue bigger expressions together from smaller ones, so it's not variables per se that have types.

Similarly, in dynamic typing, it's not the variables that lack statically known type — it's all expressions! Variables lacking type is merely a consequence of the expressions they store lacking type.

---

**One final illustration**

In dynamic typing, all the cats, dogs and even elephants (in fact entire zoos!) are packaged up in identically sized boxes.

In static typing these boxes look different and have stickers on them saying what's inside.

Some people like it because they can just use a single box form factor and don't have to put any labels on the boxes — it's only the arrangement of boxes with regards to each other that implicitly (and hopefully) provides type sanity.

Some people also like it because it allows them to do all sorts of tricks with tigers temporarily being transported in boxes that smell like lions, and bears put in the same array of interconnected boxes as wolves or deer.

In such label-free setting of transport boxes, all the possible logicistics scenarios need to be played or simulated in order to detect misalignment in the implicit arrangement, like in a stage performance. No reliable guarantees can be given based on reasoning only, generally speaking. (ad-hoc test cases that need for the entire system to be started up for any partial conclusions to be obtained of its soundness)

With labels and explicit rules on how to deal with boxes of various labels, automated/mechanized logical reasoning can be used to draw up conclusions on what the logistics system won't do or will do for sure (static verification, formal proof, or at least pseudo-proof like QuickCheck), Some aspects of the logistics still need to be verified with trial runs, such as whether the logistics team even got the client right. (integration testing, acceptance testing, end user sanity checks).

---

Moreover, in weak typing dogs can be sliced up and reassembled as frankenstein cats. Whether they like it or not, and whether the result is ugly or not. (weak typing)

But if you add labels to the boxes, it still matters that Frankenstein cats be put in cat boxes. (static+weak typing)

---

In strong typing, while you can put a cat in the box of a dog, but you can only keep pretending it's a dog until you try to humiliate it by feeding it something only dogs would eat — if that happens, it will scream out loud, but until that time, if you're in dynamic typing, it will silently accept its place (in a static world it would refuse to be put in a dog's box before you can say "kitty").

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible to reinterpret memory, there's a couple projects that implement assemblers in Python by filling a numpy array with the instructions then pointing ctypes at the memory location and calling it a function, and it's actually technically possible to swap out an object's type, but both of these examples are hitting deep, dark corners of Python that mere mortals probably shouldn't even know about.

Comment: Variables have types apart from expressions. A function definition in Haskell will have parameters (variables) that are not bound to expressions but that certainly have types. In System F and its relatives, variables (but not expressions) must be explicitly annotated with types.

Comment: Function arguments are names for the expressions that will be "placed in them" — that's what I meant conceptually; I didn't pretend I was being type theoretically correct in terminology :)

Comment: Re: "some people like to think that static typing is about variables having type, and **strong typing** is about values having type": Is this a typo? From the subsequent text, it seems that the bolded part was meant to be "dynamic typing"?

Comment: Good summary at the start, but then becomes rather judgmental. I mean: "logical reasoning can be used to draw up conclusions on what the logistics system won't do or will do for sure (static verification, formal proof, or at least pseudo-proof like QuickCheck)". At least mention that except for QuickCheck (which is useless if you do have unit tests and insufficient if you don't) all of those are pretty much research problems and are only applied to some very specific and very small subsets.

Comment: (I'm aware of people doing static verification and proofs of protocols and implementations of those, but that's about it, not full applications). The dynamic site is arguing that if you don't have unit tests it doesn't matter if your code compiles, because all the interesting bugs aren't caught by the compiler anyhow (which is why, every good project even in static+strong languages has unit tests) and unit tests will catch all bugs that a compiler would catch anyhow. On that point I agree, I do find that specifying types for interfaces as documentation is very valuable though.

Comment: Neither of your "memory reinterpretation" examples actually reinterpret memory. In fact, `int` and `char` usually have different sizes, as do `bool` and pointer types, so you *can't* reinterpret the memory of a `char` as an `int` or a pointer as a `bool`.

Comment: "(e.g. "5"+3==8 in PHP (or does it? ;)))" Was nesting that many parens in an English sentence really necessary? You'll be talking with a Lisp soon...

Comment: just 2 parens. @ruakh: no it was what I meant. dynamic typing can also mean completely weak types, like I think in Tcl where everythig is a string. Or assembly where everything is just memory.

Comment: @Voo: I knew your top tag was Java before I opened your profile page — you and I have a veeery different understanding of what types can do; therefore we also have a very different understanding when tests are unavoidable and when they are useless. In any case, reality is different from what you describe — Haskell teams actually do get away with a lot less testing, courtesy of QuickCheck and expressive types (you don't need Agda or Idris for type level verification).

Comment: @ErikAllik I was more offended the aesthetic atrocity of the nesting. See [this "TED talk"](http://xkcd.com/541/) for an explanation of the completely avoidable issue.

Comment: @Erik "Haskell teams actually do get away with a lot less testing" - citation needed and not just some anecdotes (I am actually rather interested in the topic, so if you actually have a whitepaper that I haven't seen so far I'm all ears). The interesting unit tests are about *business* requirements and a compiler can't catch incorrect implementations of those... sure you can specify more type hints, but who said you specified those correctly?

Comment: I did not say _without testing_ but with _less_ testing. Mismatches between real life business rules and spec still need to be sanity checked using tests, and so do integratIons. But all or most internal testing (spec <-> impl) can be done away with in favor of types (and QuickCheck/SmallCheck — they're way more capable than you might think). For a somewhat related case study by Don Stewart: https://www.dropbox.com/s/28rop2xvdfsvn4b/dons-google-2015-01-27.pdf?dl=0

Comment: So what's the other 0.89% of Python? ;)

Comment: @Darael: arguing about whether things are Pythonic or not.

Comment: @SteveJessop I suppose I should count myself lucky nobody pointed out my maths fail (100-(99.9+0.01) is 0.09, not 0.89)

Comment: @Voo: with a sufficiently powerful type system, you *can* encode business requirements in types. Ocsigen is a web framework written in OCaml, which cannot generate malformed HTML, any attempt to do so would result in a type error. Ur/Web is a web framework written in Ur, which cannot generate malformed HTML, dead links, SQL injections, cross-site scripting attacks, HTML forms without validations, any attempt to do so would result in a type error. Galois is a company using Haskell for government, military, and intelligence software, and they have encoded the rules for distributing classified …

Comment: … documents in the type system, making it impossible to write code that violates secrecy. Even if an evil attacker were able to inject a plugin into a government CMS by Galois, it would not be possible for that plugin to leak any information, because it wouldn't compile. And this is not even talking about dependent typing in languages like Agda, Idris, Epigram, Coq, Isabelle, where you can encode *anything* you can express in logic as a type.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does Common Lisp fit in here?

Comment: Dynamic and strong (with some numeric coercions as typical).

Comment: Reinterpretation of memory in C(++) is almost always illegal unless you go through an explicit conversion with `memcpy()` or (officially only in newer language versions, practically in any sufficiently modern compiler) a union.  In nearly all other cases, it is undefined behavior.  For example, `reinterpret_cast<foo*>` only guarantees that the reverse conversion can be performed losslessly.  You are expressly prohibited from dereferencing the intermediate pointer by the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: One important note to add, is that there is no such thing as “formal proof”. All math is ultimately based on axioms that it can’t ”formally prove” an that require verification by scientific means (reliably observing its predictions). So calling that “pseudo-proof” is inappropriate, as it leads to an unwarranted confidence and an unscientific (religious aka schizoid) way of thinking, and is also ultimately self-contradicting.

Answer (score 9):

You seem to mix up dynamic/static and weak/strong typing.

Dynamic or static typing is about whether the type of a variable can be changed during execution.

Weak or strong typing is about being able to predict type errors just from function signatures.

Haskell is both statically and strongly typed.

However, there is no such thing as variable in Haskell so talking about dynamic or static typing makes no sense since every identifier assigned with a value cannot be changed at execution.

EDIT: But like goldenbull said, those typing notions are not clearly defined.

Comment: Strong typing on its own does not let you predict anything whatsoever; it only makes sure Cats don't ultimately get treated like Dogs (think how terrible that would be for the cat...). Only static combined with strong provides that; but then again even static+weak offers a lot of predictabity.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly typed.  See section 2.3 here: [Why Haskell matters](https://wiki.haskell.org/Why_Haskell_matters#Strong_typing)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about two different things.

First, haskell, and most functional programming (FP) languages, do NOT have the concept "variable". Instead, they use the concept "name" and "value", they just "bind" a value to a name. Once the value is bound, you can not bind another value to the same name, this is the key feature of FP.

Strong typing is another topic. Yes, haskell is strongly typed, and so are most FP languages. Strong typing gives FP the ability of "type inference" which is powerful to eliminate hidden bugs in compile time and help reduce the size of the source code.

Maybe you are comparing haskell with python? Python is also strongly typed. The difference between haskell and python is "static typed" and "dynamic typed". The actual meaning of term "Strong type" and "Weak Type" are ambiguous and fuzzy. That is another long story...

Comment: sorry but you are mixing up strong and static, as well as referring to "type checking" but talking of "type inference" instead: _Strong typing gives FP the ability of "type inference" which is powerful to eliminate hidden bugs in compile time and help reduce the size of the source code._

Comment: We *do* have the concept of a variable; we just use the word a bit differently. A variable in a functional language is a lot like a *mathematical* variable.

Comment: @goldenbull: by the way the concept of "variable" has more to it than merely the difference you are highlighting — for example mathematical functions have a clear concept of a variable (and parameter and constant); since Haskell is just generalized/abstract algebra really, the line between math and programming is blurred, and hence saying _"Haskell does not have variables"_ is, while not entirely incorrect _per se_, not too informative.